# Unable to process data from MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Suppose I have a schema as: **Model1.js**:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const bookSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    someDate: { type: Date },
})
```

Based on this schema I have stored data in mongoDB as:

```
{[
    "someDate" : ISODate("2021-02-16T06:42:52.652Z"),
}]
```

when I try to filter it based on month I get the result as:

```
const info = await Model1.aggregate([...some other matchning parameters,{ $project: { month: { $month: "$someDate" } } }]).exec();

//O/p: [{  month: 2 }]
```

Now let's suppose I have another schema as : **Model2.js:**

```
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const desktop = mongoose.Schema({
    details: [{
        somAnotherDate: { type: Date },
    }]
})
```

And when I try to filter it:

```
 const info = await Model1.aggregate([...some other matchning parameters,{ $project: { month: { 
             $month: "$details[0].somAnotherDate" } } }]).exec();

  // O/p: [{month: null }]
```

So what is causing the issue and it is unable to process the date?

Type of Date saved in both condition is also same, so what is causing the issue. Or I cannot fetch the value in such way while querying MongoDB?

I tried:

```
const info = await Model1.aggregate([...some other matchning parameters,{ 
$project: { month: $unwind:"$details", {  $month: somAnotherDate" } } }]).exec();
```

But this is not allowed as it's throwing error.

Please do let me know what all methods can I apply.

**EDIT:**

Say I have data saved as

```
{details:[{"someDate" : ISODate("2021-02-16T06:42:52.652Z"),},
          {"someDate" : ISODate("2021-03-16T06:42:52.652Z")}]}
```

As per provided answer by @Cuong Le Ngoc:

```
const info = await Model1.aggregate([
  ...some other matchning parameters,
  { 
    $project: { 
      month: { 
         $month: { $arrayElemAt: ["$details.somAnotherDate", 0] } 
      } 
    } 
  }
]).exec();
```

and we can get the o/p as:

```
// O/p: [{month: 2 }]
```

But here we processed assuming we have only one element inside details array , but what if we have multiple elements. how can I iterate using the method provided as it only deals with one element.

Expected o/p as:

```
O/p: [{month: 2 },{month: 3 }]
```

Please let me know if you need any more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MongoDB, you can use [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-dot-notation) to specify query conditions for field in a document at a particular index of the array like `details.0.somAnotherDate` but it will not work in projection as mentioned [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/):

> you cannot project specific array elements using the array index; e.g. `{ "instock.0": 1 }` projection will not project the array with the first element.

To get `somAnotherDate` field of the first item in `details`, you can use [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html). For example:

```
const info = await Model1.aggregate([
  ...some other matchning parameters,
  { 
    $project: { 
      month: { 
         $month: { $arrayElemAt: ["$details.somAnotherDate", 0] } 
      } 
    } 
  }
]).exec();
```

**UPDATE**: To get month for each item in `details`, you can use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) first then project like you did with Model1:

```
const info = await Model1.aggregate([
  { $unwind:"$details" },
  { 
    $project: { 
      month: { $month: "$details.somAnotherDate" } 
    } 
  }
]).exec();
```